# Unit testing as non developer

Tags: unit-testing

How possible is it for a non-dev, Qa person, to on board themselves to learn how to unit test production code?

SI have an understanding of how code is written and understand basic logic but what do you consider the learning curve would be for me if I wanted to learn how to write unit tests for my team?  Not overnight obviously, but over time?  Is it even feasible?

Comment: You would basically need to expand your skill set to include programming of unit tests, and you would need to join the development team to coordinate which tests need to be written and will be included in the canonical test suite. This is not normally a QA responsibility, but it might be an interesting career move. Unit tests are most often not as complex as the application code, but you should have a very good understanding of the technical responsibilities of the components under test. When you say "my team" you indicate that you see yourself as part of the team, that's a good start :-)

Comment: "Unit testing" is a somewhat overloaded term; in any case, there are different kinds of testing. Developer tests are written by the developers themselves, as an intimate part of the development process, and these are meant to give rapid feedback, to serve as a safety net for refactoring, and also be a thinking tool of sorts. It makes *no sense* for anyone else but the developers themselves to write those tests (i.e., it isn't helpful, and it wouldn't work towards providing the the developers with what they need from the tests). QA professionals have a role in other kinds of testing.

Comment: Answer: **yes for testautomation; no for unittest.** As a non programmer you can easily learn how to write test automation scripts using the [Gherkin_(language)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gherkin_(language)) with `given`, `when` and  `then` and BDD framworks like Cucumber, or jBehave. Programming `Unittests` (defined as Tests in isolatation) requires a lot of developping experience.

Answer (score 1):

This hits on some ideas I've talked about before on [Software Quality Assurance & Testing](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/27737/17901) but I'll address your specific question here.

Unit testing is [white box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing). You cannot be effective at writing unit tests without understanding the code.

However, you can sit down with a developer, show them the documented manual test that you created that broke the system, and have them write a unit test in the high level domain language you should already be familiar with. You can look at the test, the names of things it asserts to be true, or equal, or less than. You can compare the reasoning you see in this unit test and sign off that the unit tests cover the same issues that your manual test covered. Do that and the manual test can be shelved and never run through again.

This can be critically important because manual QA tests can grow to the point that it takes 6 months to a year to release code.

But other than that, no, you aren't going to produce unit tests without developing your coding skills. Unit tests should be written by the people that wrote the code being tested anyway. If you started writing unit tests yourself I'd give you some programming work to do as well.

There is the idea of peer unit testing. I write some units tests and some code that makes them pass. Then I hand it over to another coder who reviews my code and writes whatever unit tests still needed to make what the code does clear. This person is a fellow coder who will eventually hand me their own code that I review and write unit tests against.

None of this is integration testing, which is falling out of favor anyway. Isolated testing (unit testing) is becoming the most preferred form of automated testing. That doesn't mean QA is going away.

QA's most important job isn't automation. It's to think of what programmers don't think of. It's a creative, imaginative job. If they're making you do repetitive mindless stuff they are wasting your talents. I love having QA help. It means I can go fast knowing they have my back.